# Syntax error in WITH as PhpMyAdmin procedure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Good day.
I have problems creating the following stored procedure in PhpMyAdmin 4.8.5 the query is as follows.

```
Create Procedure sp_TPbalonmDcdos()
WITH cte AS (
SELECT categoria,ndeporte,genero,equipo1,score1,equipo3,score3
FROM score
UNION AL
SELECT categoria,ndeporte,genero,equipo3,score3,equipo1,score1
FROM score)
SELECT ndeporte,categoria,genero,UPPER(equipo1) EQUIPOS,
COUNT(*) PJ,
SUM(score1>score3) PG,
SUM(score1<score3) PP,
SUM(score1=score3) PE,
SUM(score1) GF,
SUM(score3) GC,
SUM(score1-score3) DfG,
SUM(3*SIGN(score1>=score3)) TOTAL
FROM cte 
WHERE categoria = 'CAT 2'
AND ndeporte = 'Balon Mano'
AND genero = 'D'
GROUP BY UPPER(equipo1)
 ORDER BY FIELD(equipo1,equipo3,'AMARILLO','ROJO','TURQUEZA') DESC,equipo1,equipo3;
```

When executing this query PhpMyAdmin throws me the following error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'cte ( SELECT category, ndeporte, gender, team1, score1, team3, score3 FROM sco 'on
>   line 2

It should be noted that this stored procedure when I execute it in MYSQL 8 is executed perfectly.

I request your kind help.

Comment: What's your MySQL version? Does it support CTEs?

Comment: The problem is in phpmyadmin.

In mysql I have no problems the version I use is 8

Comment: *The problem is in phpmyadmin.* I doubt. The core of error message text is produced by MySQL. Enable General log and look the query text really sent to MySQL. I think PHPMyAdmin had altered it.

Comment: Do you have `DELIMITER` statements?

Comment: I already solved the problem, change the query, apparently it is the version of phpmyadmin does not accept the With cte clause, attached query. Thank you all for your time

Comment: In phpmyadmin your version of MySQL will be <=5.7